# cfc remote method result wrapped up in wddxpacket

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, cfc, wddx

When I return a string from my remote method from cfc. The returned string is wrapped up in a strange wddxpacket:

[image: wddxpacket]

I tried to turn off the debugging output like this:

```
<cfsetting showDebugOutput="no">
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

set `returnformat` to `plain` or `json` in the remote `<cffunction>`

see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5c.html